# How to interact with current function run with button click?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Swim is using pyqt5 to create a gui. In that gui I have a basic program to read two lineEdits, and use them to loop through and print some basic output. What I want to do is be able to edit/add to variables that are in the middle of their functions run with a button click. 
In my head I would have to add some thread creation and use IPC or something. 
Main question is that when using Qt5 if a button click causes a function to run how do I interact with that function run with another button click?
Thanks.

```
##Have to come up with way to have all 

#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QLineEdit, QComboBox
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from time import sleep
import serial
from serial.serialutil import SerialException
from serialUtil import full_port_name, enumerate_serial_ports
from helpers import RepresentsInt


mustBeInt = "MUST BE AN INTEGER"

class MainWindow(QDialog):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.title = 'Serial Test GUI'
    self.left = 50
    self.top = 50
    self.width = 320
    self.height = 100
    self.comms = []
    self.defaultIterations = 20
    self.defaultTimeout = 500

    self.initUI()
    return

  def initUI(self):
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    #self.createGridLayout()

    #windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    windowLayout = QGridLayout()
    #windowLayout.addWidget(QPushButton('1'),0,0)
    #windowLayout.addWidget(QPushButton('2'),0,1)
    #windowLayout.addWidget(QPushButton('Stop'),2,2)

    self.labelComs = QLabel("COMs:") 
    self.labelIterations = QLabel("Iterations: ")
    self.labelTimeout = QLabel("Timeout(in ms): ")
    windowLayout.addWidget(self.labelComs, 0,0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
    windowLayout.addWidget(self.labelIterations, 1,0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
    windowLayout.addWidget(self.labelTimeout, 2,0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

    self.comboboxComs = QComboBox()
    ports = self.populateComsBox(self.comboboxComs)
    windowLayout.addWidget(self.comboboxComs, 0,1)

    self.lineIterations = QLineEdit()
    self.lineTimeout = QLineEdit()
    self.lineIterations.setText(str(self.defaultIterations))
    self.lineTimeout.setText(str(self.defaultTimeout))
    windowLayout.addWidget(self.lineIterations, 1,1,1,2)
    windowLayout.addWidget(self.lineTimeout, 2,1,1,2)
    #windowLayout.addWidget(self.lineTimeout, 2,1)

    self.buttonStart = QPushButton('Start')
    self.buttonStop = QPushButton('Stop')
    self.buttonStart.clicked.connect(self.startClick)
    windowLayout.addWidget(self.buttonStop, 3,2)
    windowLayout.addWidget(self.buttonStart, 3,0)
    self.setLayout(windowLayout)



    #windowLayout.addWidget(self.lineIterations, 1,1,2,1,PyQt5.AlignCenter)
    #windowLayout.addWidget(self.lineIterations, 1,1)
    #self.lineIterations.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)//Makes the entry into the text lineEdit align to the center.
    #windowLayout.addWidget(self.lineIterations, 1,1)


  def startClick(self):
    if RepresentsInt(self.lineIterations.text()) != True:
      self.lineIterations.setText(mustBeInt)
    if RepresentsInt(self.lineTimeout.text()) != True:
      self.lineTimeout.setText(mustBeInt)
    if self.lineIterations.text()==mustBeInt or self.lineTimeout.text()==mustBeInt:
      return
    for i in range(0, int(self.lineIterations.text())):
      print("Iteration " + str(i+1) + " of " + self.lineIterations.text())
      sleep(int(self.lineTimeout.text())/1000.0)
    return

  def populateComsBox(self, comboBox):
    if 'win' in sys.platform:
      for portname in enumerate_serial_ports():
        self.comms.append(portname)
    elif 'linux' in sys.platform:
      pass
      return
    else:
      pass
      return
    self.comms.sort()
    for port in self.comms:
      comboBox.addItem(port);
    return  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = MainWindow()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that **starts** the work done on your variables with a button click should be separated from the function that **works**. The base block for this type of problem would be something like this:

```
def StarterFunction(self):
    WorkThread = threading.Thread(target=self.WorkerFunction, args=(tuple, of, arguments))
    WorkThread.start()

    while WorkThread.is_alive():
        QApplication.processEvents() # This keeps the GUI responsive.
    WorkThread.join()

def WorkerFunction(self):
    # do some work with variables
```

And for your specific problem, you want the button that started all to update the variables while the work function is running if I understood correctly? Then you can do that:

```
def StarterFunction(self):
    self.ui.button.clicked.disconnect(self.StarterFunction)
    self.ui.button.clicked.connect(self.UpdateMyVariables)

    WorkThread = threading.Thread(target=self.WorkerFunction, args=(tuple, of, arguments))
    WorkThread.start()

    while WorkThread .is_alive():
        QApplication.processEvents() # This keeps the GUI responsive.
    WorkThread.join()

    self.ui.button.clicked.connect(self.StarterFunction)
    self.ui.button.clicked.disconnect(self.UpdateMyVariables)

def WorkerFunction(self):
    # do some work with variables

def UpdateMyVariables(self):
    # read inputs from the GUI
    self.MyVariable1 = self.ui.lineIterations.text()
    self.MyVariable2 = self.ui.lineTimeout.text()
```

That last part requires you to declare the variables processed in `WorkFunction()` as attributes of the GUI class in the `__init__` so that they can be accessed and modified both by `WorkFunction()` and `UpdateMyVariables()`.

Comment: I would rather suggest to use `QThread` and connect a function to the signal `onfinished` to reset the starter function for the click signal instead of checking the thread in a loop.

Comment: This method works fine for me (at work I use it to perform measurements and still allow the user to change input values). Does `QThread` prevent the GUI from freezing too?
There the starter function is reset after the thread is finished too, because the `connect` and `disconnect` happen after `WorkThread.join()`

Comment: And what if I want multiple buttons to be able to interact with the running function?

Comment: Multiple buttons doing exactly the same thing? Just connect/disconnect more of them.

Comment: @Guimoute Yes, `QThread` does the the GUI from freezing. @NDEthos You can create multiple instances of the thread... And I really do recommend to use `QThread`, setup your own subclass and work with `pyqtsignal`s instead of "hard" programmed loops for waiting.

Comment: So what is the difference between my solution and `QThread`s? You said you recommended them but without really explaining their advantages.